# Bash: uniq count large dataset

Tags: bash, uniq

I have a set of CVS files spanning over 70GB, with 35GB being about the field i'm interested in (with around 100 Bytes for this field in each row)

The data are highly duplicated (a sampling show that the top 1000 cover 50%+ of the rows) and I'm interested in getting the total uniq count

With a not so large data set  I would do

`cat my.csv | cut -f 5 | sort | uniq -c | sort --numeric` and it works fine

However the problem I have is that (to my understanding) because of the intermediate `sort` , this command will need to hold in RAM (and then on disk because it does not fit my 16Go of RAM) the whole set of data, to after stream it to `uniq -c`

I would like to know if there's a command /script awk/python to do the `sort | uniq -c` in one step so that the RAM consumption should be far lower  ?

Comment: Did not test it, but [this blog](http://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/alternative-to-sort-uniq-c/) pretends it is possible with `awk`.

Comment: @jm666 It is my understanding that it holds a __hash__ of the whole row which should lower memory consumption. If even an array of hashes of unique lines won't hold in your memory you'll have to use another method. Do you have enough storage to create a copy of your dataset?

Comment: @jm666 My bad should have read more extensively. The author indeed uses `hash` for what I know as an `associative array`.

Comment: @jm666, I run it once in a while , so speed is appreciated but not required, it's more that I have a 100Go disk and 16RAM currently the command is finishing because sort run out of space in both RAM and Disk.

Comment: @silel I'm currently running your solution , I should soon be able to tell you if it works and how many times it took

Comment: normally I think I will end up with ~5 million uniques or less, so it should holds up in ram, otherwise yes I think I will fallback to a quick and dirty C program that hold in RAM only a 64 or 128 bits murmurhash  of each string

Comment: The `sort`s that I have used can sort any size file, as long as you have enough disk space for 2nd copy (plus some space for other stuff going on). Because it will default to writing the intermediate sets to the `/tmp` dir, you may easily run of of space in that partition. Check you `man sort` and see what option you need to provide to to use an alternate directory (usually `-T/path/to/big/dir`) . Also, as long as you have enough disk space, I don't think `sort` worries too much about available RAM. (It will use it if it can). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
perl -F, -MDigest::MD5=md5 -lanE 'say unless $seen{ md5($F[4]) }++' < file.csv >unique_field5.txt
```

it will holds in the memory 16byte long md5-digest for every unique `field-5` (e.g. `$F[4]`). Or you can use

```
cut -d, -f5 csv | perl -MDigest::MD5=md5 -lnE 'say unless $seen{md5($_)}++'
```

for the same result.

Of course, the md5 isn't cryptographically safe these days, but probably  will be enough for sorting... Of course, it is possible to use `sha1` or `sha256`, just use the `-MDigest::SHA=sha255`.  Of course, the sha-digests are longer - e.g. needs more memory.

It is similar as the `awk` linked in the comments, with a difference, here is used as hash-key not the whole input line, but just the `16byte` long MD5 digest.

#### EDIT

Because me wondering about the performance, created this test case:

```
# this perl create 400,000,000 records
# each 100 bytes + attached random number,
# total size of data 40GB.
# each invocation generates same data (srand(1))
# because the random number is between 0 - 50_000_000
#    here is approx. 25% unique records.
gendata() {
perl -E '
    BEGIN{ srand(1) }
    say "x"x100, int(rand()*50_000_000) for 1..400_000_000
'
}

# the unique sorting - by digest
# also using Devel::Size perl module to get the final size of the data hold in the memory

# using md5
domd5() {
    perl -MDigest::MD5=md5 -MDevel::Size=total_size -lnE '
        say unless $seen{md5($_)}++;
        END {
            warn"total: " . total_size(\%seen);
        }'
}
#using sha256
dosha256() {
    perl -MDigest::SHA=sha256 -MDevel::Size=total_size -lnE '
        say unless $seen{sha256($_)}++;
        END {
            warn"total: " . total_size(\%seen);
        }'
}

#MAIN
time gendata | domd5    | wc -l 
time gendata | dosha256 | wc -l
```

results:

```
total: 5435239618 at -e line 4, <> line 400000000.
 49983353

real    10m12,689s
user    12m43,714s
sys 0m29,069s
total: 6234973266 at -e line 4, <> line 400000000.
 49983353

real    15m51,884s
user    18m23,900s
sys 0m29,485s
```

e.g.:

for the md5

- memory usage: 5,435,239,618 bytes - e.g. appox 5.4 GB
- unique records: 49,983,353
- time to run: 10 min

for the sha256

- memory usage: 6,234,973,266 bytes - e.g. appox 6.2 GB
- unique records: 49,983,353
- time to run: 16 min

In contrast, doing the plain-text unique search using the "usual" approach:

```
doplain() {
        perl -MDevel::Size=total_size -lnE '
                say unless $seen{$_}++;
                END {
                        warn"total: " . total_size(\%seen);
                }'
}
```

e.g running:

```
time gendata | doplain | wc -l
```

result:

- memory usage is much bigger: 10,022,600,682 - my notebook with 16GB RAM starts heavy swapping (as having SSD, so a not big deal - but still..)
- unique records: 49,983,353
- time to run: 8:30 min

Result?

just use the

```
cut -d, -f5 csv | perl -MDigest::MD5=md5 -lnE 'say unless $seen{md5($_)}++'
```

and you should get the unique lines enough fast.

Comment: I think for performance you can even use a non cryptographic hash like murmur

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
split --filter='sort | uniq -c | sed "s/^\s*//" > $FILE' -b 15G -d "dataset" "dataset-"
```

At this point you should have around 5 `dataset-<i>` each of which should be much less that `15G`.

To merge the file you can save the following bash script as `merge.bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash
#

read prev_line
prev_count=${prev_line%% *}

while read line; do
    count="${line%% *}"
    line="${line#* }" # This line does not handle blank lines correctly
    if [ "$line" != "$prev_line" ]; then
        echo "$prev_count $prev_line"
        prev_count=$count
        prev_line=$line
    else
        prev_count=$((prev_count + count))
    fi
done

echo "$prev_count $prev_line"
```

And run the command:

```
sort -m -k 2 dataset-* | bash merge.sh > final_dataset.
```

*Note: blank line are not handled correctly, if it suits your needs you can remove them from your dataset or correct `merge.bash`.*

Comment: will it run in parallel or sequentially ?

Comment: You will have to check `split`'s documentation, but I don't think the merge part is parallelizable. This works much like the map/reduce paradigm.